# Creating login system in node/mongodb/express. can't connect to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a login system where an admin can log in and look at data that is not available to the public. Right now I'm just trying to find my admin instance in my database. I have two node files:     `app.js` and     `account_manager.js`

`app.js`

```
//creates node app
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var AM = require('./account_manager');

//stuff...
/***************************************
LOGIN 
***************************************/
app.post('/login', function(req, res){

    AM.manualLogin(req.param('username'), req.param('password'), function(e, o){
        if (!o){
            res.send(e, 400);
        }   else{
            req.session.user = o;
            res.send(o, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

`account_manger.js` is required in `app.js` and is stored in AM

`account_manager.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');


var admin_db = mongoose.connection; 

admin_db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));
//connection open?
admin_db.once('open', function callback(){
   console.log("User Database connection open!\n");
 });
var User_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({username: String, password: String});

var Admin = mongoose.model('Admin', User_Schema);

exports.manualLogin = function(user, pass, callback)
{
admin_db.find({username: user},function(err,docs){ //error is here
    if(docs){
        var x = 0;
        var flag = false;
        while(docs[x]){ //goes through all the admins
            if (docs[x].param("username") == user){ //if it's a match
                callback(null, docs);
                flag = true;
                break;
                }
            x+=1;
            }
        if (flag == false){
            callback('invalid-password/username');
            }
    }

});
}
```

I get a `TypeError` that says:

```
Object #<NativeConnection> has no method 'find'
```

what's my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still quite new to node.js myself, but I'll try and answer anyway.

It looks like you've properly built your connection to mongodb through mongoose, but you have not created a schema.  While mongodb doesn't have schemas, mongoose does.

What you'll need to do is create a schema (UserSchema) that matches the construction of a user document in your users collection, then create an instance of that schema (User) which is now your model, then call .find on that model.

The Mongoose Quick Start guide goes through this process:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

EDIT after update:

You are currently calling admin_db.find.  This does not exist.  This is the error you are getting.

You need to change that to Admin.find.  You also need to understand what the difference is.

EDIT once more:

You're not properly using the admin_db.once callback.

I suggest you go back and reread the Mongoose Quick Start guide I linked.  It's quite short and goes through all of this.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I have a schema in my `account_manager.js` I just decided to not include it. Edited to include it

Comment: Changed my answer to reflect your changes.

Comment: Wow that was a silly mistake. Thanks for helping me track it down!

Answer (score 2):

I see you're rolling your own system here, but I thought I'd share a link to Drywall in case you could gain some inspiration or knowledge from it.

Drywall - A website and user system for Node.js: http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/

I hope this is helpful. Feel free to open issues in GitHub if you run into any road blocks.